# How to cancel auto delete blank lines vs code?

Tags: settings, visual-studio-code

I have a typescript files and when I add something and saving, auto delete blank lines is working, after that I have to accept all incoming changing for gitlab. How can I cancel this auto delete blank lines?

```js
    {
       "region_of": "Your location",
       "list_emtpy": "Your list is empty",

       "no_task_for_animal": "There is no task for this animal",
       "scanner_select_obj_help": "Please enter barcode number",

       "animal_id": "animals IN"
    }
```

If I will save this file, there will be not any blank lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to settings, write on `Search settings` -> `auto delete blank line` choose `typescript` block's, in the end uncheck `Typescript>Format:Enable` and saving your settings. Your `.json` files will not auto delete blank lines.

Comment: there is no -> "auto delete blank line" option !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question about allowing empty lines in a .ts file, TypeScript does not allow empty lines in .ts files because they are not valid JavaScript syntax. However, you can use comments to create empty lines in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings or use shortcut `Ctrl + ,` search for Insert Final Newline and Trim Final Newline that should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

From search settings, check:

```
Format: Keep Lines
Keep all existing new lines when formatting.
```